# authotkey: stopping/ending current hotkey thread containing multiple blocks

Tags: automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

```
3::
;code with sleep timers here
loop 5{
;code with sleep timers here
}
;code with sleep timers here
```

I have a hotkey setup like above. I would like to be able to stop it while its running, ideally with any wasd keypress, less ideal hitting same key (3) again. All the docs I have read rely on use of BREAK...which only breaks the immediate loop. Tossing the entire code in a second loop and breaking didn't work:

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
3::
Toggle := !Toggle
loop, 1{
;code
loop 5{
If not Toggle
        break
;code
}
    If not Toggle
        break
}
return
```

I tried PAUSE instead of break but I don't want the current thread saved I want it reset. I tried SUSPEND but it only stops future hotkeys...it finishes the one its currently running. I tried EXIT with #persistent but it didn't work as desired either. Again, what I want is for the current hotkey that is in the process of running to stop and reset as if it ended normally...without compromising my other hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a nice way (that I'm aware of) for doing this in AHK <sup><sub>(at least without some very deep magic)</sub></sup> but it is trivial in [AHK_H](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/).

What's AHK_H?

> AutoHotkey_H adds functionality to original AutoHotkey and offers true multi-threading using NewThread() function (v2 only) and AutoHotkey.dll.

Now I'm not going to recommend for, or against, you learning/using AHK_H, I'm just going to present this as an option.
Also I'm going to be writing AHK-v2, since I don't really see any point writing AHK_H-v1, and H-v1 is also missing some functionality compared to H-v2.

So in AHK_H(v2) you can do for example the following:

```
script1 := "
(
ToolTip("Hi from Thread1, step1")
Sleep(1000)
Loop 5
{
    ToolTip("Hi from Thread1, loop" A_Index)
    Sleep(1500)
}
ToolTip("Hi from Thread1, step2")
Sleep(5000)
ToolTip("Bye from Thread1, the end")
Sleep(1000)
)"

script2 := "
(
ToolTip("Hi from Thread2, step1")
Sleep(2000)
Loop 5
{
    ToolTip("Hi from Thread2, loop" A_Index)
    Sleep(1750)
}
ToolTip("Hi from Thread2, step2")
Sleep(3000)
ToolTip("Bye from Thread2, the end")
Sleep(1000)
)"


1::
{
    global script1, Thread1
    if (IsSet(Thread1))
        Thread1.ahkterminate()
    Thread1 := AhkThread(script1)
}

^1::
{
    global Thread1
    if (IsSet(Thread1))
        Thread1.ahkterminate()  
}


2::
{
    global script2, Thread2
    if (IsSet(Thread2))
        Thread2.ahkterminate()
    Thread2 := AhkThread(script2)
}

^2::
{
    global Thread2
    if (IsSet(Thread2))
        Thread2.ahkterminate()  
}
```

First we're defining two separate AHK scripts to the variables `script1` and `script2` just as plain text strings.
A continuation section<sup>[(docs)](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation-section)</sup> is used for this.

Then the hotkey `1::` is defined.
Here we first say that we're using using the variables `script1` and `Thread1` outside of that hotkey's scope<sup>[(docs1)](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Concepts.htm#variables)</sup> <sup>[(docs2)](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/Concepts.htm#variables)</sup>, just as you would need to do in AHK-v1 for functions. In v2 you need to do it for Hotkeys as well.
Then we check that if the variable `Thread1` has already been set<sup>[(docs)](https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/commands/IsSet.htm)</sup>, we want to terminate it before running it again with `ahkThread`<sup>[(docs)](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/docs/commands/AhkThread.htm)</sup> (unless you want to be able to run multiple of the same script at the same time).

Then the hotkey `^1::` is defined.
Here we can just terminate thread1 whenever we want by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

And then the exact same stuff is done for number 2.

---

This is, of course, a very simple example where no communication between the threads, or anything more special, is needed. But of course all of that is very doable as well.

To run your AHK_H-v2 script, download AHK_H-v2 [here](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/), and run your `.ahk` file via the AHK interpreter found in the folder `x64w`.
(How? For example just drag and drop your `.ahk` file on top of `AutoHotkey.exe`)

For reading the AHK_H documentation, I recommend the `.chm` file that comes with the download.
It tends to be better/more up-to-date than the online documentation.

For learning AHK-v2 itself, here's a documentation page to get you started:
https://lexikos.github.io/v2/docs/v2-changes.htm
AHK-v2 just came out of the alpha stage and is now in the beta stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different hotkey and reload the script.

```
your_hotkey::
reload
```

Or simply use `reload` instead of `break` if your current code works like that.